# maths integral question (needs to be done by a computer)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, computer-algebra-systems

$$\int_0^\infty \left( 1 - \left(1 - e^{-\frac{2x}{24}}\right)^{11}\left(1 - e^{-\frac{x}{24}}\right)\left(1 - e^{-\frac{x}{72}}\right)^{2}\left(1 - e^{-\frac{2x}{144}}\right)^{2}  \right) \ dx$$

Hey Guys!!

- I have been trying to integrate the above question but cannot do it
  because it is too long and therefore, needs to be done by a computer (as it over 50+ terms!!!)
- The problem is that i do not have my computer software which can do it for me so i thought you guys can help me out by doing it.
- If you have a smarter way, i am all ears.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Have you tried putting $u = \exp(-x / 144)$?

Comment: Sure, no problem! It is $\sim 238.02373448509798.$ :)

Comment: Have you tried WolframAlpha? http://www.wolframalpha.com 
Type something like: 

int ... from 0 to infinity

Comment: What made you delete the same question you asked a moment ago and ask it again with almost exact wording?

Comment: It's 19179385249735728551550367428216940591727383888374120235641/80577616728959000543177737840861586668464761577474749000 to be exact, by the way.

Comment: Guys, no need to downvote - everybody has to hear about WA for the first time at *some* point.

Comment: Santiago,  i have not
Marvin F: I am tried but it doesn't work on my phone.

Comment: Lovsovs: Thank you very much

Comment: Try the mobile version of their website then: http://m.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @Lovsovs : Thank you very much for your help but It says you need to go pro. I just needed the answer and i am very grateful that you have helped me. :)
Is there is a way to select your answer as the best answer?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have not learned this complex integration yet and i was getting a lot of negative attention because people believed it was my homework. For my first question, i got no answer and for my second question here I got a lot of negative comment and downvoting just because i needed help to understand a concept.

Comment: Then download their app, I think it is 5 dollars or something (def. worth it if you do not have access to a computer, where it is free). I could make an answer, which you could accept.

Comment: @Lovsovs My parents do not allow me to buy apps :( 
Please do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral evaluates to

$$\frac{19179385249735728551550367428216940591727383888374120235641}{80577616728959000543177737840861586668464761577474749000}$$ $$\approx 238.02373448509798.$$

Such computations can usually be carried out on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) (click [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/) for mobile version).

Alternatively you could try the substitution suggested in the comments ($u=e^{x/144}$).